# Python rstrip and split

Tags: python, split

Hi I want to remove strip newline from my list and get the third word for each element. I am using split and rstrip. This is my code:

```
# obtain just compound ids from list
just_compound_id = []
for line in final_list:
    split_file = line.split(' ')
    split_file = line.rstrip()
    just_compound_id.append(split_file[2])
    print(just_compound_id)
```

but I get a really weird output, something like this

```
['I']
['I', 'I']
['I', 'I', 'I']
['I', 'I', 'I', 'I']
['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I']
```

**EDIT

this is my input

```
['UNIQUE-ID - ASN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - D-GLT\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 4-AMINO-
BUTYRATE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-8569\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-17095\n', 'UNIQUE-ID 
- CPD-17880\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - GLY\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-18298\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 
D-SERINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - ACETYLCHOLINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - DOPAMINE\n', 
'UNIQUE-ID - SEROTONIN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - HISTAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 
PHENYLETHYLAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - TYRAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-58\n', 
'UNIQUE-ID - 1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL-2-METHYLAMINOETHAN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 
TRYPTAMINE\n']
```

Comment: Please give an example of your Input. Also, rstrip() before splitting.

Comment: Are you really want rewrite `split_file`? :)

Comment: So, I changed the order (btw why does strip have to be before split?). But I still dont get the \n stripped from my list

Comment: @smvpfm If you want just strip new line I advise to you `final_list =
 [el.replace('\n', '') for el in final_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `split_file.split(' ')` instead of `line.split(' ')`, and also you need to do the `line.rstrip()` before the `split_file.split(' ')`:

```
just_compound_id = []
for line in final_list:
    split_file = line.rstrip()
    split_file = split_file.split(' ')
    just_compound_id.append(split_file[2])
    print(just_compound_id)
```

The way you have it currently, the first assignment to `split_file` has no effect since you don't use it and you overwrite it in the next assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[e.rstrip().split('-')[2] for e in finallist]
```

Comment: @smvpfm Is it what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is regex if you have more complicated input. For the case above, I recommend splitting lines using `-` and set the `maxsplit` parameter.

```
final_list = ['UNIQUE-ID - ASN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - D-GLT\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 4-AMINO-BUTYRATE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-8569\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-17095\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-17880\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - GLY\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-18298\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - D-SERINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - ACETYLCHOLINE\n',
              'UNIQUE-ID - DOPAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - SEROTONIN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - HISTAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - PHENYLETHYLAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - TYRAMINE\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - CPD-58\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - 1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL-2-METHYLAMINOETHAN\n', 'UNIQUE-ID - TRYPTAMINE\n']
just_compound_id = []
for line in final_list:
    line = line.rstrip()
    split_id = line.split('-', 2)[2].strip()
    just_compound_id.append(split_id)
print(just_compound_id)
```